# Returning different results or throwing exceptions from successive calls to Moq Mock

Tags: mocking, moq

I get a Moq object to return different values on successive calls to a method. This is done by this extension method:

```
public static void ReturnsInOrder<T, TResult>(this ISetup<T, TResult> setup, params TResult[] results) where T : class
{
    setup.Returns(new Queue<TResult>(results).Dequeue);
}
```

Now I want one of the calls to throw an exception while others return something. Has anyone done this before?

If i do this

```
mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod())
    .Throws(new Exception());
mock.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod())
    .Returns("ok");
```

then the the first setup is overwritten and only the second setup persists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used callback chaining while developing retry proxy.

```
var src = new Mock<ITest>();
src.Setup(s => s.RaiseError()).Callback(() => 
src.Setup( s => s.RaiseError())).Throws<Exception>();

const int retryCount = 1;
var proxy = RetryProxy.MakeFor(src.Object, retryCount);

proxy.RaiseError();
src.Verify(s => s.RaiseError(), Times.Exactly(retryCount+1));
```

Comment: This (rather convoluted) solution is not necessary anymore since Moq has support for the SetupSequence method.  See my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 12):

Nowadays Moq (version 4+) supports this through its `SetupSequence` method.  See [this post](http://codecontracts.info/2011/07/28/moq-setupsequence-is-great-for-mocking/) for an introduction.

Comment: But in the official release it does not allow for returning a value from mocked method after throwing an exception (still possible to do this in reverse order) - https://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=319

Answer (score 8):

Phil Haack [blogged about this](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/29/moq-sequences.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use `SetupSequence(...)` on the mock object.

For example the following will throw the exception on the first call and return `someResponse` on the second call:

```
myService.SetupSequence(s => s.PlaceOrder())
    .Throws(new Exception())
    .Returns(someResponse);
```

Comment: Throws returns void so this order is not allowed (using Moq version 4.0)

Comment: Are you sure? Cos I'm using this actual line of code and it works fine for me.  I'm using Moq version 4.0.30319.  Are you sure your "PlaceOrder()" (or equivilent method) is actually being called?

Comment: I'm using Moq.WithoutCastle -Version 4.0.10827.2 and the code won't compile. Perhaps it is a limitation of Moq.WithoutCastle.

Comment: Errr why the -1? This works when using standard Moq 4.0 or greater.